# c# xxx is a variable but is used like a type

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

i have a model in my xamarin forms app that is used to generate a dynamic navigation menu

```
 public class NavigationMenuItem
 {
        public string MenuText { get; set; }
        public string MenuIcon { get; set; }
        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
 }

 NavigationMenuItems.Add(new NavigationMenuItem
 {
        MenuText = "Settings",
        MenuIcon = "settings.png"
        TargetType = typeof(SettingsViewModel)
 });
```

i have some code that allows me to navigate to a page via the page's view model so that a view model never references a page directly but via its view model.  this works when i hard code the view model :

```
await _navigator.PushAsync<PageViewModel>();
```

but if i try

```
 var vm = selectedItem.TargetType;
 await _navigator.PushAsync<vm>();
```

i get an error "vm is a variable but is used like a type"

how can i pass the type held in `TargetType` into `PushAsync`

thanks in advance

jas

Comment: Except in the title no where in your code I see `xxx` variable.

Comment: You can't use an instance of `Type` as a generic type parameter.  Is there no overload for `PushAsync` that has a `Type` parameter? e.g. `PushAsync(Type type)`?

Comment: @HariPrasad XXX is just a placeholder name. Actual variable name is vm.

Answer (score 1):

`PushAsync` is expecting a type at compile time to tell it which method it needs to call.

If you don't know until runtime then you either need to pass the view model as an argument:

```
await _navigator.PushAsync(vm);
```

or implement the navigation on the view model:

```
await vm.PushAsync();
```

Comment: i have tried 'await _navigator.PushAsync<vm>();' but this also give me the same error   'vm' is a variable but is used like a type

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an instance of `Type` as a generic type argument to that method. But you could use reflection to achieve that:

```
var vm = selectedItem.TargetType;

MethodInfo mi = _navigator.GetType().GetMethod("PushAsync`1");
MethodInfo genericMethod = mi.MakeGenericMethod(vm);
await (Task)genericMethod.Invoke(_navigator);
```

So you retrieve the `MethodInfo` for the generic method definition and create a specific `MethodInfo` by providing the type to `MakeGenericMethod`.
Finally you can invoke that method and cast the returned object into a `Task` that you can await.